# Converting a pandas dataframe into bool values

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, boolean

I am trying to write a code that checks if there are any duplicates in the `Unix` column in the  pandas series. It is supposed to return a `bool` value of `True` for `DataSet` since `130` is repeated twice and a `False` for `DataSet2`. How would I be able to get the expected output below?

```
import pandas as pd

DataSet = pd.DataFrame({'Unix':[130, 140, 150, 130],
                  'Value':[11,2,3,4]})
DataSet2 =  pd.DataFrame({'Unix':[130, 140, 150, 160],
                  'Value':[11,2,3,4]})
 
print(DataSet.duplicated(subset=['Unix']).bool())
print(DataSet2.duplicated(subset=['Unix']).bool())
```

Expected Output:

```
True 
False
```

Comment: `DataSet.duplicated(subset=['Unix']).any()`

Comment: Why is the `DataSet2` result `False`? There are duplicates in the `Unix` column in both.

Comment: For the 2nd print line, didn't you mean `DataSet2.duplicated(...`? You wrote `DataSet` instead of `DataSet2`

Comment: how about `~DataSet2['Unix'].is_unique`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `.any()` which returns `True` if there are any truthy values in the collection passed to it as an argument (conversely, `.all()` returns `True` only if all values in a given collection are truthy):

```py
In [5]: DataSet.duplicated(subset=['Unix']).any()
Out[5]: True

In [6]: DataSet2.duplicated(subset=['Unix']).any()
Out[6]: True
```

However, I think you may have accidentally copied the wrong data for `DataSet2` as it is identical to `DataSet1` and a `False` answer wouldn't make sense.

Note that you can also use `.is_unique`, which is more appropriate for your use-case:

```py
In [7]: DataSet.Unix.is_unique
Out[7]: False

In [8]: DataSet2.Unix.is_unique
Out[8]: False
```

For reference, the `.any()` and `.all()` functions are convenience methods that are logically equivalent to using `or` and `and`, respectively, over all the items in a collection.

Comment: Yea I have made a mistake but it does work thank you. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.any()` instead of `.bool()`:

```
print(DataSet.duplicated(subset=['Unix']).any())
print(DataSet2.duplicated(subset=['Unix']).any())
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

(Note that `DataSet` and `DataSet1` as given in the question are identical, thus `True` for both. I assume this is just a typo and does not reflect your actual data.)

Answer (score 0):

you can get DataSet True following code

```
print(DataSet["Unix"].duplicated().sum() > 0)
```

i don know why DataSet2 is False